# Enter data to 2 tables

Tags: javascript, mysql, arrays, laravel-5

I'm doing a shopping module. The code is already made to enter the sales table and sales detail. When I enter a product it works correctly but when I want to enter more than two products at the same time I get this error:

> Uninitialized string offset: 1

It is worth mentioning that the data is sent through a matrix with js and in the controller I receive it through the while loop. This is the JavaScript code:

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#bt_add").click(function(){
        agregar();
  });
});
   var cont=0;
   total = 0;
   subtotal=[];
   precioIva=[];

  $("#guardar").hide();
  $("#pidConcepto").change(mostrarValores);

  function mostrarValores() {
    datosArticulo=document.getElementById('pidConcepto').value.split("_");
    $('#pprecio').val(datosArticulo[1]);
    $('#pimpuesto').val(datosArticulo[2]);
  }

  function agregar() {

        datosArticulo=document.getElementById('pidConcepto').value.split('_');

        idConceptosPagos=datosArticulo[0];
        consepto=$("#pidConcepto option:selected").text();
        precio=$("#pprecio").val();
        impuesto=$("#pimpuesto").val();
        cantidad=$("#pcantidad").val();

        if(consepto!=" " &&  precio!=" " && impuesto!=" " && cantidad!= " ")
        {

              precioCantidad = precio * cantidad;
              iva = precioCantidad * 16 / 100;
              subtotal[cont] = precioCantidad;
              precioIva[cont] = iva;
              total1=precioIva[cont]+subtotal[cont];
              total=total+total1;

              var fila ='<tr class="selected" id="fila' + cont +'" ><td><button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" onclick="eliminar('+cont+');">X</button></td><td><input type="hidden" name="idConceptosPagos[]" value="'+idConceptosPagos+'">'+consepto+'</td><td><input type="text" name="precio[]" readonly="readonly" style="text-align: right;" value="$/. '+precio+'"></td><td><input type="text" name="cantidad[]" disabled  value="'+cantidad+'"></td><td type="text" name=precioCantidad[] style="text-align: right;" readonly>$/.'+precioCantidad+'</td><td type="number" style="text-align: right;" name=iva[]>$/.'+iva+'</td><td style="text-align: right;">$/.'+ total1+'</td></tr>';

              cont++;
              limpiar();
              $("#total").html("$/. " + total);
              $("#total_venta").val(total);
              evaluar();
              $("#detalles").append(fila);

        }else {


              alert("Error al ingresar el detalle de la venta, revise los datos del articulo");

        }
  }

function limpiar() {
  $("#pfechaPago").val("");
  $("#pprecio_venta").val("");   
 }

  function evaluar(){

  if (total>0) {
        $("#guardar").show();
  }
  else {
       $("#guardar").hide();  
  }
}

function eliminar(index) {

 total=total-subtotal[index];
 $("#total").html("$/. " + total);
 $("#total_venta").val(total);
 $("#fila" + index).remove();
 evaluar();
}
```

and in the controller I do it this way:

```
$venta = new VentaUtp;
$venta->idAlumno=$request->get('idAlumno');
$venta->idCiclo=$request->get('idCiclo');
$venta->clave=$request->get('clave');
$venta->anio=$request->get('anio');
$venta->mes=$request->get('mes');
$venta->pagado= 'N';
$venta->cantidadProgramada = $request->get('total_venta');
$venta->cantidadPagada = null;

$venta->save();


$idAlumno = $request->get('idAlumno');
$idCiclo = $request->get('idCiclo');
$idConceptosPagos = $request->get('idConceptosPagos');
$precio = $request->get('precio');
$pcantidad = $request->get('pcantidad');

$cont=0;

while ($cont < count($idConceptosPagos)) 
{
    $detalle = new DetalleVentaUtp;
    $detalle->idAlumnoCxC= $venta->idAlumnosCxC;
    $detalle->idAlumno = $idAlumno[$cont];
    $detalle->idCiclo = $idCiclo[$cont];
    $detalle->idConseptoPago= $idConceptosPagos[$cont];
    $detalle->cantidad=$pcantidad[$cont];
    $detalle->save();
    $cont= $cont + 1;
}
```

I think the error comes from this assignment:

```
$cont = 0;
```

But I do not know why. How can I solve this?

Comment: You need to output the data you are sending from JavaScript to PHP to make sure that it is sent correctly.  That error message means that one of the items you are passing has a lower array count than $idConceptosPagos.  Maybe run the PHP code and output the array count of each of the variables.

Comment: what is mean?..